# VB6 Type Mismatch in For loop condition

Tags: vb6, for-loop, type-mismatch

I have been trying to find out why in the following code, the third time through the loop I am getting a Error type 13 Mismatch when the line "For lCount = 0 To maxCount" is being evaluated. I had originally thought the problem was in getting the value from the vArray, but testing shows it to be triggered by the "For" line. I haven't a clue as to how the type would be changing during the processing of the loop. Thanks!

```
    Public Function FindCodeIndex(vArray As Variant, MatchValue As String) As Integer
    ''This function locates a value in a combo box returning the index or -1 if not found
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim maxCount As Long
    Dim arrayStr As String


    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    maxCount = UBound(vArray)


    For lCount = 0 To maxCount
    arrayStr = vArray(1, lCount)

        If UCase$(arrayStr) = UCase$(MatchValue) Then
            FindCodeIndex = Int(lCount)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next lCount

    FindCodeIndex = -1

    Exit Function


ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Unexpected error in frmComment::FindCodeIndex()" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Code: " & CStr(Err.Number) & " Error Desc: " & Err.Description
```

Comment: You don't assign `arrayStr` to any value. Are you sure that isn't the problem?

Comment: Added assignment (from memory, not at work PC now) to arrayStr. Testing shows the loop fails at the For statement on the third pass.

Comment: Tim, can you use the locals window to see the data in the array that's being used in the third pass, and edit your question to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function FindCodeIndex(Array() As String, ByVal MatchValue As String) As Long

    Dim index As Long
    Dim upper_bound As Long

    upper_bound= UBound(Array)
    MatchValue = UCase(MatchValue)

    For index = 0 To upper_bound
        If UCase(Array(index)) = MatchValue Then
            FindCodeIndex = index 
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next index 

    FindCodeIndex = -1

End Function
```

Comment: VB definitely doesn't like that solution, complaining about Array() not being defined. 

Most recent test shows that setting a Long = -1 is also throwing an error(?)

Comment: @Timbuck. `Array` is not a valid identifier in VB6, because it conflicts with the built-in `Array` function.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I'm unsure why ChaosPandion put this code here, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The function mentions that the code is being written for a ComboBox (are you actually copying each item in the List() method into an array and sending this to your function?).  This seems a little over-complicated if you are using the standard VB ComboBox.  Just use the following code:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByRef wParam As Any, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT As Long = &H158

Public Function FindCodeIndex(ByRef cmb As ComboBox, ByRef sMatchValue As String) As Long
'This function locates a value in a combo box returning the index or -1 if not found

    FindCodeIndex = SendMessage(cmb.hWnd, CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, ByVal -1, ByVal sMatchValue

End Function
```

It is a lot quicker and smaller to use the Windows API in this case.

Comment: That's somewhat bad commenting on my part - and also related to a bad decision made about ten years ago by another developer. Effectively what I have is an array with two rows, the first being a list of code descriptions and the second being the associated list of codes. The function above looks through the array for the matching code value, and sets the combobox listindex = to the position of the array the item was found. The combobox shows the code descriptions.